# How to setup Typescript 2.0 with visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

### My questions are

1. How did you setup typescript with visual studio 2015 in a nutshell?
2. How do you make sure the @types are same version as npm package?**

### Background Question 1

I have tried to update to typescript 2.0 but can't get intellisense and have errors when compiled.

I have package.json pointing to my types:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/react": "^2.0.41",
    "react": "^0.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

I also tried to add this to my tsconfig(without comments of course):

```
//"typeRoots": [
//  "node_modules/@types"
//]
```

I don't know if  this is needed anymore. I would guess not?

### Background Question 2:

The question about versioning is more general. I have had so many issues with my types from definitely typed. This is why I moved to 2.0 since I thought it would be more consistent. However I still get these errors:

```
   ERROR in C:\Users\alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Projects_CleanDir\clean\react-hot\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\history.d.ts
    (9,23): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/alexander/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Projects_CleanDir/clean/react-hot/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/history"' has no exported member 'Location'.

    ERROR in C:\Users\alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Projects_CleanDir\clean\react-hot\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\history.d.ts
    (9,103): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/alexander/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Projects_CleanDir/clean/react-hot/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/history"' has no exported member 'Location'.

    ERROR in C:\Users\alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Projects_CleanDir\clean\react-hot\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\history.d.ts
    (10,26): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/alexander/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Projects_CleanDir/clean/react-hot/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/history"' has no exported member 'Pathname'.

    ERROR in C:\Users\alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Projects_CleanDir\clean\react-hot\node_modules\@types\react-router\lib\history.d.ts
    (10,46): error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/alexander/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Projects_CleanDir/clean/react-hot/node_modules/@types/react-router/lib/history"' has no exported member 'Query'.
```

Is this a version issue? Maybe something else.... Should it not just work...

Comment: I had several attempts to do the config, and always I gave up and finished up with using VSCode which looks like is created for TypeScript, which hardly can be said about VS

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting for Question 1?